# How to check more than one checkbox individually in DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview

I would like how to achieve this, I tried many of the solutions i found on here on SO but none of them worked

[image]

I want to be able to check for example the first and the second option but when i check one of them the others two are unchecked, how can avoid this?

I would like to know what events or properties i need to change to be able to select multiple checkboxes individually no using a master checkbox to select all of them, I hope you can help me thanks.

I tried this code in the `CellClick` event of the datagridview

```
var isChecked = (bool)DGVProductos.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;

if (isChecked)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DGVProductos.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Index != e.RowIndex)
        {
            row.Cells["CheckProducto"].Value = !isChecked;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp Look at the code, there is a validation and your solution didnt work

Comment: Step one: Don't write code that does what you don't want. Step two: Decide how your code can know which rows you want to affect. You can loop over the DGV.SelecteRows

Comment: @TaW Step one: I wrote it on here so that way you can see what i tried before

Comment: Well, the code unchecks each but the clicked line. Simply don't do that. And don't forget step 2!

Comment: @TaW that is why i said I TRIED that code, so im not using it anymore

Comment: Sure. But: You need to understand both what you want and what you write.

Comment: Sure. But: You need to understand that if I don't add any code to the question you would say "where is the code?" or "what have you tried so far?"

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem.  A CheckBox column doesn't behave like a Radio control.  In the desired CheckBox Column, you should be able to check as many CheckBox cells as you wish by default.  Surely there is some other code at fault here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your `foreach` loop is trying to accomplish, but it is unchecking all of the other boxes that are not the row that was checked.  If you want the boxes checked individually and to stay checked, remove the `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear what you try to achieve there, the code you wrote does exactly the opposite from what you are describing, just remove that code and you should be able to check individual cells.

Though if you are trying to use that column as a Selection-Indicator, thus the column is not bound to any property, note, that this is not possible, since the column is not bound to the objects checking 1 row-cell will automatically check all rows and vice versa.

**Side Note:** Whatever you want to achieve, code that needs to run when a user check/uncheck a checkbox, should be invoked on `CellContentClick` event rather then `CellClick` event.

Comment: Cellcontentclick can be tricky, not always recommended! Also he may (or may not) want to check more than one checkbox in one click. But we can't know..

Comment: I argue that you lookup the SourceCode for WinForms and you will see in fact that the DataGridViewCheckBoxCell changes to Check/Uncheck in coordination with CellContentClick, not CellClick.

Comment: Hm, interesting!

Comment: @Professor Zoom did you read my answer? Is the issue indeed because the column is Unbound Column? If so I might have a workaround for you.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution to what I was trying to achieve I will let the code on here for reference to anyone else facing this same issue

```
private void DGVProductos_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
    {
        if ((bool)DGVProductos.SelectedRows[e.ColumnIndex].Cells["CheckProducto"].Value == false)
        {
            DGVProductos.SelectedRows[e.ColumnIndex].Cells["CheckProducto"].Value = true;
        }
        else
        {
            DGVProductos.SelectedRows[e.ColumnIndex].Cells["CheckProducto"].Value = false;
        }
    }    
}
```

This way i'm able to check more than one checkbox indivually like the question says, not sure if is the best way but this worked for me